# Create Date column from a matrix which has days in rows, years in columns

Tags: r

I have a matrix, daily data with days as rows (1-31) and years along the top (currently labelled V1-38).

I want to get this into standard Dataframe format - with a date column and value column, like so:

```
1981/01/01   2.3
1981/01/02   2.5
1981/01/03   2.2
```

But it currently looks like this:

```
        V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7       V8       V9      V10
1 2.725555 1.747722 2.339690 2.567638 2.132981 2.533396 1.451677 3.611268 2.397998 2.346086
2 0.000000 1.845749 1.527552 1.940177 2.622369 3.051540 1.963055 1.738778 3.503306 2.876869
3 3.473171 2.408620 3.302557 2.438352 2.780118 3.429249 2.680390 2.611921 3.888107 1.846845
4 3.903236 3.018319 2.494222 2.847573 2.755765 3.278010 2.733373 2.235076 1.278947 3.300032
5 3.212206 2.734175 2.558577 1.981932 2.620426 2.854362 2.876913 3.546763 1.102284 3.318756
6 3.497115 2.830972 1.772694 1.503301 2.653948 3.563540 1.801707 3.867459 1.418526 2.085040
```

I know the starting date for both the days and the years.  I loaded the matrix into a dataframe from a list

```
index <- as.data.frame(List$matrix)
```

and it formats it as shown above.

Comment: Use `dput` to show us your matrix.

Comment: If it's `31` rows then it's always `January` (I mean "\*/01/\*")?

Comment: And where are the months ?

Comment: It actually has 3 months worth of data, so the rows go from 1-91 (for AMJ).  One month carries on into the next, so row 31 is the 1st May in this case.